# Top-hang or traditional twin-slot shelves for books?

Tags: shelving

We want to hang bookshelves on a wall that's about 2.2m high by 3.8m wide. We are considering a twin-slot system, for example by [Elfa](https://elfa.com/en/assortment/system). But even within that choice, there are options, specifically between a top-hang system vs traditional wall-mounted uprights.

In terms of geometry, we were thinking 7 shelves vertically and probably three 1.2m shelves (230mm deep) horizontally to fill 3600mm.

(One embarrassing problem: I can't quite figure out what the wall is made out of. It's an exterior wall of an old (late-19th C) UK home. It's certainly backed by brick, but isn't just masonry -- it sounds slightly hollow, but a stud-finder doesn't really see anything. There are a few screws with plastic anchors used as picture hangers from the previous owners already in the wall.)

The main question: would the top-hang system be sufficiently strong for bookshelves? It is certainly much easier to install than the traditional uprights which require 5 screws each and very precise alignment.

Any other hints/ideas for this problem?

Comment: I would **not** trust "top hang". I would go with traditional uprights, each installed into studs or masonry or some other very strong material. **Books are heavy**. So the first step is to figure out what your wall is really made of.

Comment: This is really an opinion type question, I would also go traditional also.